# Getting issue while integrate TFVC with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, tfvc

I am trying to integrate TFVC in the android studio with this [plugin](https://java.visualstudio.com/docs/tools/androidstudio) . I have also downloaded **tf** command line and install and register successfully. Still, I am facing issue for check out from TFVC. I am getting error that is: **The team service plugin required tf command line tool to be installed and configured in Settings menu.**

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. This may help you if you stuck in same issue.

We need to set tf executable path in **VERSION CONTROL => TFVC**

Following are the steps which need to follow to set up tf executable path.

1. Go to File then Settings in the toolbar for Windows and Linux. For Mac, go to Android Studio then Preferences.
2. Choose Version Control from the left menu then TFVC.
3. In the Path to tf executable text field, navigate to the location of the tf executable.
4. Click Test to test that the executable has been found and is working as expected.
5. Click Apply then OK to save and exit.